# Non-singular matrices forms a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Do the set of all non-singular matrices forms a group under multiplication. ?

I don't think it does as the multiplication operator is not even defined for every two element in the set .

Just need a confirmation.

EDIT 1 : Non-singular means that determinant is not equal to zero.

Comment: You should fix the size of the matrixes to be $n\times n$, for some fixed integer $n$.

Comment: @Raclette The question is as stated , there is no restriction for the size of the matrices .

Comment: Then they do not form a group, as multiplication is not well-defined in general.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to confirm this. It was asked in a competitive exam and the answer is said to be true.

Answer (score 4):

If by "non-singular" you mean that the determinant is $\neq 0$, then the answer is yes, since you are dealing with square matrices and $\det (AB)=\det A \det B$. If you mean that the rank is maximal and you are considering $m\times n$-matrices, then the answer is no because multiplication is not even defined unless $m=n$.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear: What is the definition of "non-singular" matrices? Whether the matrices are defined over a field or not?

Assume that the matrices are square matrix of a fixed size and non-singular means determinant non-zero. If the matrices are defined over a field then the answer is yes. But if the matrices are defined over a (commutative) ring then it's not true, because in a ring not every element has a multiplicative inverse. But if you define non-singular by insisting that the determinant is a unit in the ring, then they form a group.

Comment: If you take *all* square matrices with nonzero determinant, over say a field, then they do not form a group. But, if you take all square matrices of size $n\times n$, then it's another question.

Comment: @Raclette: I'll edit my post accordingly. Thanks for the point. I was thinking of same "size" matrices only, not the variable ones.

Comment: @Krish My statement in the question "I don't think it does as the multiplication operator is not even defined for every two element in the set ." is regarding the same issue.

Comment: @AtulGangwar: then it's not. I missed that point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No , as you are saying the multiplication on a nxn non-singular matrix and a mxm non-singular square matrix is not defined(if n and m are different ) .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. PLease use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).